# Implementation ListAdapter and possible memory leaks

Tags: android, listadapter

I have a very simple Activity:

```
public class A extends ListActivity implements ListAdapter
{
    @Override public void onCreate(Bundle b)
    {
        super.onCreate(b);
        setListAdapter(this); //no problems without this line
    }
    // etc... (empty implementation ListAdapter interface functions)
}
```

When I start this Activity from other activity:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, A.class));
```

and bush "back" button (to destroy this activity), the heap grows up about 13..15 kbytes and doesn't reduce back even after GC works out.
When I start and finish this activity again, the head grows up more and more.
To monitor the heap size I use DDMS in Eclipse.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You might try running it without debugging. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910473/i-have-a-memory-leak-using-listactivity-in-android/6530551#6530551

Answer (score 1):

I would really urge you not to implement ListAdapter in the same class as your Activity. Its not a good programming practice and all the Android tutorials create separate classes as adapters. They certainly do not merge the adapter and activity into one class. For example consider the [GridView tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html) as an example of my point.

The problem lies where you say `setListAdapter(this)` in my opinion. "this" refers to the ListActivity class A, which is not an adapter by any means. for the correct use of setListAdapter you should pass either an [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) or create your own Adapter class (which implements ListAdapter, and extend BaseAdapter) and instantiate it.

I think this may solve your problem, as your setting the adapter of the view to the activity itself, which seems recursive or a kind of "infinite loop" in some nature.

Comment: Correct me if I wrong, but there is no difference beetween implementation of ListAdapter interface or BaseAdapter subclass.

Comment: P.S. I mean, the BaseAdapter is just an empty implementation of ListAdapter and SpinnerAdapter interfaces.

Comment: Yes that is true, there is no great difference between ListAdapter or BaseAdapter, only that ListAdapter has a couple of extra methods. I should have said "implements ListAdapter or extend BaseAdapter" in my answer. You would still need to place this is a separate calss for the reasons i stated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you cache views inside `getView()` method of `ListAdapter` implementation? If the answer is yes then caching may be a reason of memory leaks. For example leaks can happen because of using static members or `View.setTag(int, Object)` for storing views.

Anyway I recommend you to install [MAT Plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/), start and finish this activity for 5-10 times and analyze heap. After that you'll be able to see leaked objects and root of leaked object hierarchies.